# Gettting list items with specific field value

Tags: list, powershell, pnp-powershell, item, sharepoint-server

Is there an easy way to get all list elements that have the same value in a column?

Let's say I have a list with a column called system.

Is there a possibility to get all items with the value "Windows" in the system column?

I could not find any parameter of `Get-PnPListItem` that could fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`-Query`** parameter to filter the list items by using CAML Query.

**Reference**:
[Get-PnPListItem Examples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps#examples) - Check Example 5.

Try Something like below:

```
$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List YOURLISNAME -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='System'/><Value Type='Text'>Windows</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: I have tried this command: `$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List ImportTest -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='itSystem'/><Value Type='Text'>EDM Cosima</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>" -Fields "name","system","admin", "read","write"` Now it says that the parameter set cannot be resolved. Does that mean I can't use the Query and Fields parameter together?

Comment: I am not a PowerShell expert.But you can try using `ViewFields` like `$listItems= Get-PnPListItem -List YOURLISNAME -Query "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="ID" /><FieldRef Name="Title" /><FieldRef Name="Name" /></ViewFields><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='System'/><Value Type='Text'>Windows</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"`. Use internal names of field in Query.